# Mule4 equivalent code for Mule3 mel/dw code

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

We are migrating a project from mule3 to mule4 and encountered below MEL or DW code after migrating using MMA. Any inputs on how to convert these into mule4 code is appreciated. There are variables which might confuse for eg. appendix, muleOverrideColumns etc.

```
mel:flowVars.appendix.put(flowVars.currentCode, new java.util.HashMap())

mel:flowVars.appendix.get(flowVars.currentCode).put(payload.Value, payload.Definition)

mel:flowVars.muleOverrideColumns.split("!")

mel:payload.split("!")

mel:flowVars.appendix.get(flowVars.currentCode).put(payload[0], payload[1])

mel:appendix.get(propertyKey).get(payload.getValue()) != null ? payload.setValue(appendix.get(propertyKey).get(payload.getValue())) : payload.setValue(payload.getValue())

mel:appendix.get("m3/m4").get(payload.getValue()) != null ? payload.setValue(flowVars.appendix.get("m3/m4").get(payload.getValue())): payload.setValue(payload.getValue())
```

Comment: Each of those require providing the data types for payload and flowVars. Also please split into separate questions. Some can be grouped together.

Comment: hi @aled the variables are json objects

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I have removed some of them, will ask in a separate question

Comment: Saying JSON object is very ambiguous. Please provide the Java class and if not from the standard Java library then the full package and from what library. The ones about split() doesn't seem to be methods of "JSON Objects". 
About splitting the question, you should do it based on some logical criteria, no the first n and the rest. For example all the methods using get() in one question, all the uses of split() (if they are always the same method). What about the replace usage? Also you should provide more context. From where do the JSON Objects come?